# Exposing Web Application as Web Service too

Tags: web-services, spring

I have an web application developed in spring. Now I need to expose certain functionality as Restful Web services. I am not supposed to use Spring Rest features.  Below are my questions,

1) Can I use the same codebase as a web app as well as Web service?

2) If the answer to the first one is yes then with very less or minimal changes what would be the best approach for converting web app classes(or some functions) to restful web services? AXIS2 or Jersey? For Jersey, I could see that sample tutorials available in the internet its mostly annotation driven and as my spring web application is already filled with annotations such as @AutoWired,@Component etc I am not sure using Jersey annotations on top of spring annotation would lead to conflicts.

Comment: If you're not supposed to use REST features, does your company have another standard for exposing REST-style services that you should use instead?

Comment: @Jonathan I meant spring provided REST features cannot be used.

Comment: Right. I meant Spring-provided REST features. Usually if a company prohibits you from doing that, they have another idea in mind (CXF, Jersey, Rest Easy, etc.)

Comment: They have insisted on using AXIS2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the same code base, but not as same.. you need to replace some annotations with jersey's annotation as a Web Service is all about its URL and Methods, So need to place URL Path to the methods and have to define request-responce method (post/get) methods over the Java classes and methods.

Also, you need to make xml controllers or wrappers with jersey annotations that will receive the posted xml inputs and produce required xml output, Or JSON as you decide.

Acc to me, Working with jersey will be much similar to spring annotations and easy too.

Comment: If I use Jersey and replace some spring annotations with jersey annotations then wont spring flavor of the application get lost? The same code base should work fine as spring web app and as a web service. Is it possible to do that? I want to know at the initial stage itself so that i am in the right direction.

Comment: Spring and Jersey are two different things. Yes, you need to modify come code and annotations accordingly. Its all about Annotations like Path Annotations.